# C#/Visual Studio 2022: Microsoft.mshtml doesn't appear under Solution-Explorer->Add->Project-Reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Trying to follow these instructions to add mshtml reference to my C#/WPF Application in Visual Studio 2022:

```cs
using Microsoft.mshtml;

// Project → Add Reference
// Go to the Extensions tab (under Assemblies) on the left
// Make sure the checkbox next to Microsoft.mshtml is checked.
// Press OK.
```

But Microsoft.mshtml doesn't Show up under project references for some reason... any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Here's what I expect it to look like, but it doesn't look that way:

[image]

Comment: It's under COM. Read your own comment.

Comment: its not... the "Assembly" tab is missing under references form...

Comment: I'm looking to add Assembly "Microsoft.mshtml",,,, missing from form for some reason...

Comment: has something to do with using .Net core 3... But, doesn't fix the problem when i switch back to .Net 6... however...

Comment: The screenshot above is on .Net 6. I'm not going to tell you again, it's under COM.

Comment: Microsoft.mshtml is a PIA (primary interop assembly), no longer used in a .NETCore or .NET 5+ project.  Click the Browse button, select c:\windows\system32\mshtml.tlb.  Beware that VS goes catatonic for a while.  Fwiw, I've been hearing rumors of Windows Update actively uninstalling Internet Explorer and its components, WebView2 is the replacement.

Comment: Hi Bimo, if you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)