MSHTML reference in a Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11
I've got a solution that includes a reference to MSHTML. The laptop was recently updated to Windows 11 and I'm not sure if that's a coincidence however the reference looks like its erroring so I removed the reference and I'm trying to add it again however I receive the following error. Any suggestions on how to add a reference to MSHTML?


related (see the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996206/c-visual-studio-2022-microsoft-mshtml-doesnt-appear-under-solution-explorer

I was able to reproduce the issue you are experiencing. This is mainly because mshtml.dll is not a file that can be directly referenced as an assembly or COM component. However, you can try to use tlbimp.exe to convert the COM type library (mshtml.tlb) to a managed assembly:
1: Open the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (Run as Administrator).
2: Run the following command to convert the COM type library to a managed assembly:
tlbimp.exe "C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb" /out:"C:\mshtml.dll"
3: Wait until the command runs successfully with a few warnings, it will display TlbImp: Type library imported to mshtml.dll
4: Open your project in Visual Studio and right-click the References node in Solution Explorer. Select Add Reference. In the Browse tab, click the Browse button and select the C:\mshtml.dll file that you just generated. After adding the reference, right-click the added mshtml.dll, select Properties, and set Embed Interop Types to Yes.
